# Regex for checking that at least 3 of 4 different character groups exist

Tags: javascript, regex, passwords

I'm trying to write a password validator.

How can I see if my supplied string contains at least 3 different character groups?

It's easy enough to check if they are existant or not ---but at least 3?

- at least eight (8) characters
- At least three different character groups

  upper-case letter

  lower-case letter

  numeric

  special characters !@#$%&/=?_.,:;-\

(I'm using javascript for regex)

Comment: Btw, @Yonder, why do you need just one regexp? Do you want to put it to some JS-validation controls?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

> Just to learn - would this kind of requirement be possible to implement in pure regex?

That'd make it a rather hard to read (and therefor maintain!) solution, but here it is:

```
(?mx)
^
(
  (?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])                # must contain a-z, A-Z and 0-9
  |                                                # OR
  (?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[!@\#$%&/=?_.,:;\\-]) # must contain a-z, A-Z and special
  |                                                # OR
  (?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@\#$%&/=?_.,:;\\-]) # must contain a-z, 0-9 and special
  |                                                # OR
  (?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@\#$%&/=?_.,:;\\-]) # must contain A-Z, 0-9 and special
)
.{8,}                                              # at least 8 chars
$
```

A (horrible) Javascript demo:

```
var pw = "aa$aa1aa";
if(pw.match(/^((?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])|(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[!@#$%&\/=?_.,:;\\-])|(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#$%&\/=?_.,:;\\-])|(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#$%&\/=?_.,:;\\-])).{8,}$/)) {
  print('Okay!');
} else {
  print('Fail...');
}
```

prints: `Okay!`, as you can see on [Ideone](http://ideone.com/RcVPg).

Comment: As an aside, I've always wanted regex to have the ability to store patterns. I find myself re-using patters quite a few times for it to not be a meaningful option. Basically, something like `(?\A[a-z])` to assign `\A` to `[a-z]`. Guess I'll keep dreaming.

Comment: @Brad, that _is_ a nice idea. You can build your pattern up from strings of course and concatenate them and do `new RegExp(a+"@"+a)`, where `a` is a predefined pattern-string. (but you're probably aware of it...)

Comment: @BartKiers: That's what I have been doing, just for ease of maintainability, but it'd be nice to see "regex macros". Maybe force definition at the beginning of the pattern, then allow use for the duration of that pattern. ;-)

Comment: @Brad, many regex-enthusiast would welcome such trickery (like me), but, as you may know, for every regex-enthusiast, there are probably about 10 people that are against introducing such short-cuts in an already "hard to read" language. :)

Comment: @BartKiers: I agree, need we bring back `:labels` and `goto`s? And you know what they say about solving a problem with regex: [now you have two problems](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/06/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems.html). :grin:

Comment: Thanks for the hard core pure regex solution :) It does the trick

Comment: @Yonder, you're welcome. Needles to say, I'd never use it in "real life". Brad's suggestion is the one I'd go for.

Answer (score 9):

May as well join in on the fun:

```
String.prototype.isValidPW = function(){   
    // First, check for at least 8 characters
    if (this.length < 8) return false;

    // next, check that we have at least 3 matches
    var re = [/\d/, /[A-Z]/, /[a-z]/, /[!@#$%&\/=?_.,:;-]/], m = 0;
    for (var r = 0; r < re.length; r++){
        if ((this.match(re[r]) || []).length > 0) m++;
    }

    return m >= 3;
};

if ("P@ssW0rd".isValidPW()) alert('Acceptable!');
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/RQL8r/2/)**

Comment: Nice one. Note that you need not escape the `.`, `$` and `?` inside a character class.

Comment: @BartKiers: Funny story with that: I escaped the `]` by accident and was getting JS errors. A little puzzled that the pattern wasn't being accepted, I escaped everything and one-by-one removed the `\`s. Then, a head scratch later, I caught it and forgot to unescape the rest. :oops: ;-)

Comment: Most cool will be to put it not in String.proto, but in some another object. And also to create those regexps once, like:
http://jsfiddle.net/XnPb4/

Comment: This was my favorite solution, but none of the solutions provided ensured that **all** the characters were of the acceptable type. For instance, a single quote (') would alert 'Acceptable!' here. My quick fix was to change the return to: `return (m >= 3 && this.match(/^[0-9a-zA-Z!@#$%&\/=?_.,:;-]+$/));`

Answer (score 5):

I am assuming that you will be using different regexes for different requirements. In that case, tell me if the following work for you:

```
var e = password.match(/.{8,}/); //At least 8 chars

var a = password.match(/[0-9]+/); //numeric
var b = password.match(/[A-Z]+/); //Capitals
var c = password.match(/[a-z]+/); //small letters
var d = password.match(/[!@#\$%&/=?_.,:;-\\]+/); //special chars

if (a + b + c + d > 2 && e) {// Success}
else {// Failure}
```

Comment: Very nice and simple solution to understand. Very readable. Thanks.

Comment: Just to learn - would this kind of requirement be possible to implement in pure regex?

Comment: @Yonder: Yes and no. You can validate that it has an `[A-Z]`, `[a-z]`, `[0-9]`, `[<special>]` but not that there are 3 out of 4 (that I'm aware) without breaking it out in to separate functionality.

Comment: By the way - is it necessary to escape the characters when put in a character class, ie. in [] brackets?

Comment: @Yonder: Only characters that are meaningful to regex. e.g. a period (`.`) means "any character", so when you want a literal period you would use `\.`. Same for `$` (End of line), `/` (in this case because it's pattern wrapper), `?` (means character is optional, or ungreedy flag), `-` within a class (`[]`) means range so you can either use it at the end of the class or escape it, etc.

Comment: It`s not correct in using match, but main idea is clear. Also Bryce`s solution lost length. I`ll post resulting and most beauty solution now :)

Comment: @Crimson: As it returns to us array. Then ["1"] + ["a"] becomes "1a" in my Chrome console. Array transforms to string -- not to int.

Answer (score 3):

http://jsfiddle.net/aSsR8/6/

```
/**
 * Function determine, wheter we have valid password
 * 
 * @param {String} value
 * @return {Boolean}
 */
function isValidPassword(value) {
    // Here we define all our params
    var validLength = 8,
        minSuccess  = 3,
        isNumeric   = + /\d+/.test(value),
        isCapitals  = + /[A-Z]+/.test(value),
        isSmall     = + /[a-z]+/.test(value),
        isSpecial   = + /[!@#$%&\/=\?_\.,:;\-]+/.test(value);

    if (value.length < validLength) { // 8 symbols. We don`t need regexp here
        return false;
    }

    if (isNumeric + isCapitals  + isSmall + isSpecial < minSuccess) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}


document.writeln(isValidPassword('abc'));
document.writeln(isValidPassword('abc123ABC'));
document.writeln(isValidPassword('abc123!23'));
```

Comment: since when does `... = + ...` work with an arithmetic operator after the assignment?

Comment: It`s a shorthand to type cast to int. I saw it somewehere here yesterday :)

Answer (score 0):

Crimson's answer didn't work for me. Here is what I have.

```
var mystring = 'bLahbla\\';
var valid_char_count = 0;
var lc = mystring.match(/[a-z]+/);
var uc = mystring.match(/[A-Z]+/);
var dc = mystring.match(/[0-9]+/);
var sc = mystring.match(/[\!\@\#\$\%\&\=\?\_\.\,\:\;\-\\]/);

if( lc ){ valid_char_count++; }
if( uc ){ valid_char_count++; }
if( dc ){ valid_char_count++; }
if( sc ){ valid_char_count++; }

if( valid_char_count >= 3 ){ /* success */ }
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do all that in one regex

`^.*(?=.{8,})(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[\d\W])(?=.*[!@#\$%&/=?_\.,:;-\\]).*$`

Comment: i should add that IE6 doesn't support lookahead

Comment: Doesn't grab 3 out of 4 for me. "Password" & "PassWord" are acceptable per this pattern (missing either a numeric or a special to be valid).

Comment: This one seems to work for me...Password and PassWord fails for me, but PassW0rd succeeds

Comment: IE6 does indeed support lookahead; it's just buggy, [as explained here](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/regex-lookahead-bug).  I don't know if that's been fixed yet, but I'm pretty sure it was still broken in IE7, at least.  The workaround is to do the minimum-length check - `(?=.{8,})` - before the other lookaheads, which you're already doing.

Comment: Do you need two .* pattern matches (1 before the look aheads and 1 after them)? It seems like you would only need 1 '.*' between ^ and $. Also, this doesn't ensure you have 3 of 4 classes. You **have** to have an uppercase character and a lower case character; and you have to have at least a digit or special character. For instance, 'pa$$w0rd' would not match, even though it has 3 classes.