# Javascript regular expression for "at least X characters, have a capital letter and a number"

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a regular expression for a password field which I know works perfectly i.e. Must be at least 6 characters in length, have a capital letter, a number and can contain special characters.  When I try to apply this regex within Javascript it doesn't seem to validate.  My Javascript function is below.

```
function (word) {
    var weakRegEx = new RegExp('(?=^.{6,}$)((?=.*\d)|(?=.*\W+))(?![.\n])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z]).*$');
    var result = weakRegEx.test(word);
    return result;
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. This is pure Javascript, has no  jQuery in it. Retagged accordingly.

Comment: May be worthwhile to check out [this other SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5950756/regex-for-checking-that-at-least-3-of-4-different-character-groups-exist) which does something similar to what you're looking for. Also, I recommend using [gskinner.com](http://gskinner.com/) and make sure it's matching what you want first.

Comment: By the way, as an aside, I hate sites that try to tell me what kinds of characters I have to use in my password with a passion. It's usually reason enough for me to turn away from the site, and never come back.

Comment: Surely you would want the user to have a secure password?  By stating that they must have a capital letter and a number in their password increases the complexity of their password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're writing a string literal, you need to escape the `\` characters.

You should use a regex literal instead:

```
var weakRegEx = /(?=^.{6,}$)((?=.*\d)|(?=.*\W+))(?![.\n])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z]).*$/;
```

Comment: Still matching "Password" from my testing, shouldn't it also require a numeric?