# How to match 2 out of 3 groups with a non-password-related regular expression in Python?

Tags: python, regex

I've looked at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5950756/regex-for-checking-that-at-least-3-of-4-different-character-groups-exist) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22204836/regex-to-find-3-out-of-4-conditions) to try to figure out my problem, but I'm not sure they're directly applicable because a) I don't have a condition that always has to be met, and b) the document is so messy that allowing for any of the three to match would result in a large amount of false positives.

So, with that being said, here is my issue. I have lines of text that I want to match that look like this:
`x = "10/04             Some brief description blah blah   blah     45.00"`

where the spacing between everything is messy. Then, I have some lines of text that I want to match that look like this:
`y = "VJ../VI           Another stupid brief description    1000.00"`
`z = "11/13         This is another description   LO05.13"`

The regular expression I'm currently using is this:
`regex = r"^(\d\d\s?[1/]\s?\d\d\s?[1/]\d\d)\s+(\S+(?:\s+\S+)*?)\s+(-?\s?[\d,]+\.\d\d)"`

The problem is that in `y` `regex` doesn't match because there is no date at the beginning of the string; the OCR process messed up. However, we still know that it's a valid line because it has a description and an amount. `regex` won't match `z` either because the amount is not a bunch of digits, but we know it's a transaction because there's a date and a description.

I've considered changing the regex to look like this:
`regex = r"^(\d\d\s?[1/]\s?\d\d\s?[1/]\d\d\s+)?(\S+(?:\s+\S+)*?)\s+(-?\s?[\d,]+\.\d\d)?"`

But I'm worried that that will just match everything in the document (i.e. "Withdrawals and Debits"). And since the two optional pieces of the line of text are on opposite ends of the more consistent piece of the text, I'm not sure how to implement `|` like in the solutions to the questions I linked.

Is my best option to just make two different regular expressions, linked with `|`, like so?
`regex = r"^(\d\d\s?[1/]\s?\d\d\s?[1/]\d\d\s+)?(\S+(?:\s+\S+)*?)\s+(-?\s?[\d,]+\.\d\d)|^(\d\d\s?[1/]\s?\d\d\s?[1/]\d\d)\s+(\S+(?:\s+\S+)*?)\s+(-?\s?[\d,]+\.\d\d)?"`

Any assistance would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Instead of describing what you are doing you should be describing what you are trying to achieve. Provide a relevant sample of the input and the expected output, along with an explanation of how they are related.

Comment: Try [`r'^(\w+[^\s/]*/\w{2}\b.*?)\s*(\d+\.\d{2})$'`](https://regex101.com/r/wU2lZ3/1)

Comment: @Tomalak You have a relevant sample of the input, both some that work with the current regex (`x`) and some that don't work with the current regex (`y` and `z`). You also have the expected output: match `x`, `y`, and `z`. They're related because they're all lines I want to capture and should all be captured with one regular expression. The description of what I'm doing is aimed to show what I've tried, which is preferred on SO. So... please tell me how your comment is useful?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Trying it now. I'll let you know what the outcome is.

Comment: I understand it may overfire, but with OCR, it is a Russian roulette. That is why it would nice if you could generalize the cases, try to put them into concrete guidelines: starts with 1-4 non-whitespace, followed with `/` followed with 2 alpha... ends with a float number. Something like that.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yeah, there are approximately 500,000+ lines of text in this and the regex I had worked for almost all of it thanks to generalizing. But there were some edge cases I was hoping to get using an "at least n matches" approach. Your regex needed a slight tweaking to fit my specific needs, but it's the perfect approach and is matching what I hoped it would match. Care to post as an answer?

Comment: This is not something that is going to work. The reason is you don't have a clear definition of the one, two or three parts. Each part can be a subset of the other and are without distinction. No matter what you try, something will fail the test. When tweaked because of that, something that worked before won't work now.

Comment: @sln I'm afraid you're right in terms of actually being able to say "2 out of 3 matches" for the exact reasons that you stated. In addition to the slew of false positives that would roll in. I'm able to achieve what I wanted using Wiktor's regex, but in terms of answering the question I actually answered, I think you're right.

Comment: I posted my suggestion with explanation and suggestions.

Comment: Well, I tell you right now, any regex based on just those strings will fail down the road. You're wasting your time. The best bet is to _stare_ at a sh**t load of samples piled up and to find a common thread. Use that to divide and conquer.

Comment: I hope nobody comes here and see's the answer you've accepted as something that might actually work. You should not post questions that can't be answered and accept answers in the face of the limitations outlined. That is pollution of a solution's site.

Comment: @sln The answer was accepted with a detailed reason for why it was accepted. As for your disdain for the approach, it's anecdotal and unfounded. The revised regex provided by Wiktor is working fine and has completely solved my problem. MMV for future viewers' situations, but that's true of quite a few answers on this site.

Comment: The problem is not solvable!! The question is moot as are your other points..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With OCR inputs, it is hard to work out a 100% safe approach. Without the actual output to look at, we can only suggest a general idea on how to deal with each concrete case.

Here, I suggest

```
r'^(\w+[^\s/]*/\w{2}\b.*?)\s*(\d+\.\d{2})$'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wU2lZ3/1)

The pattern is rather a general one:

- `^` - start of string/line
- `(\w+[^\s/]*/\w{2}\b.*?)` - 1+ alphanumeric symbols or underscore (perhaps, `\w+` could be replaced with `\w`) followed with 0+ non-whitespace and non-`/` characters followed with `/`, then followed with exactly 2 "word" characters followed with a word boundary `\b` and then as few as possible 0+ characters other than a newline
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespace
- `(\d+\.\d{2})` - the final float number that can have 1+ digits in the integer part and 2 in the decimal part
- `$` - end of string/line

Playing around with the [**limiting quantifier**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#limit) and [**character classes**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html), you can further fine tune the pattern.

Comment: The reason for my question to find a way to find lines of text that were close to matches that I had already successfully matched. I wanted to create an interactive approach to parsing where the computer could identify near hits and ask the user if it was a true hit or a false positive. I thought the way to do this was through matching two of the three groups, but this regex successfully matches the close hits. Therefore, I'm considering the question answered. The regex was tweaked to match my specific data, but it served its purpose. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution suggested in the title is to break the things you are looking for into a series of more focused regex's and then see how many of them you meet.

For example I made:

```
regex = r"\d\d/\d\d"
regex_2 = r".*\s[\d]+\.\d\d"
```

Then did:

```
for i in [x,y,z]:
  tests = [re.match(regex, i), re.match(regex_2, i)]
  print sum([1 if j else 0 for j in tests])
```

And got:

```
2
1
1
```

I'd need more info before writing the third regex for the description, but I think this is the way forward.