# Is there a way to merge these two regex?

Tags: javascript, java, regex, passwords

I need check out a password string with these rules:

- Only lower-case letters, upper-case letters, numbers and some special characters (see below) are allowed.
- Minimun of 8 characters and maximum of 16.
- Password must contains at least one character from three of the four following groups:

  - Lower-case letter
  - Upper-case letter
  - Numeric character
  - Special character (!@#$%&/=?_.,:;-)

For accomplish this goal, I made two validations. The easy one is the first step, check out the allowed characters and lenght:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9!@\#$%&/=?_.,:;\-]{8,16}$
```

The second one is a little bit more complex, but I could resolve it thanks to this [Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22204836/regex-to-find-3-out-of-4-conditions):

```
^((?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])|(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[!@\#$%&/=?_.,:;\-])|(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@\#$%&/=?_.,:;\-])|(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@\#$%&/=?_.,:;\-])).{8,16}$
```

I think that probably, a 2 steps solution is clear and easy .. but... **Is there a way to merge both regex?**

I would like to apply the solution on Java, JavaScript and Lua.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me start out by emphasising that I dislike your password policy. Why do you ban other symbols, or passwords over 16 characters? Don't include those rules, if at all possible.

I've written this regex in extended form (i.e. ignores white-space), for clarity:

```
/\A 
  (?=.{8,16}\z)                     # Must contain 8-16 characters
  (?!.*[^a-zA-Z\d!@#$%&\/=?_.,:;-]) # Must not contain other characters
  (?=.*\d)                          # Must contain a digit
  (?=.*[a-z])                       # Must contain a lower case character
  (?=.*[A-Z])                       # Must contain an upper case character
  (?=.*[!@#$%&\/=?_.,:;-])          # Must contain a symbol from this list
/x
```

The above pattern solves the problem for enforcing *all four* of your rules. You could, in theory, wrap the last 4 conditions into four "or" groups - like your original example has done.

However, again, I would not recommend it. Your code would be much more legible, useful and maintainable if you do this as a series of separate checks inside a function. (For example, this means you can display more helpful error messages rather than just "regex failed!".

But since you asked.... Here is the regexp monster:

```
/\A 
  (?=.{8,16}\z)
  (?!.*[^a-zA-Z\d!@#$%&\/=?_.,:;-])
  (
    (?=.*\d)
    (?=.*[a-z])
    (?=.*[A-Z])
  |
    (?=.*\d)
    (?=.*[a-z])
    (?=.*[!@#$%&\/=?_.,:;-])
  |
    (?=.*\d)
    (?=.*[A-Z])
    (?=.*[!@#$%&\/=?_.,:;-])
  |
    (?=.*[a-z])
    (?=.*[A-Z])
    (?=.*[!@#$%&\/=?_.,:;-])
  )
/x
```

Remove all whitespace, if you don't want/have access to the `/x` modifier.

Comment: The password policy is a requirement of my cilent and he has implemented this policy in other systems, so is very difficult to change it currently. Thanks @TomLord for your solution and advice!

Answer (score 0):

A downside to a single regex for this whole validation is, the regex gets quite hard to read and maintain. Seperating the regex conditions into a single check for each condition and a simple check for the length of a String would be a more fitting and more readable solution. In my opinion the following code does the validation of the password as good as a single regex, but it´s better to maintain and read.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(isPasswordValid("Ab$123456"));
    System.out.println(isPasswordValid("b$11234566"));
    System.out.println(isPasswordValid("Ab$1234634634534252"));
    System.out.println(isPasswordValid("$112512312512"));
    System.out.println(isPasswordValid("A$115 223"));
}   

private static boolean isPasswordValid(String password) {
    // The password is to short or to long
    if(password.length() < 8 || password.length() > 16) {
        return false;
    }
    int matchedConditions = 0;
    // Check for invalid characters
    if(password.matches(".*[^A-Za-z0-9!@#$%&/=?_.,:;-].*")) {
        return false;
    }
    // is an uppercase letter present, increase matched condition
    if(password.matches(".*[A-Z].*")){
        ++matchedConditions;
    }
    // is a lowercase letter present, increase matched condition
    if(password.matches(".*[a-z].*")){
        ++matchedConditions;
    }
    // is a numeric value present, increase matched condition
    if(password.matches(".*[0-9].*")){
        ++matchedConditions;
    }
    // is a special character present, increase matched condition
    if(password.matches(".*[!@#$%&/=?_.,:;-].*")){
        ++matchedConditions;
    }
    // Return if at least 3 conditions were met
    return matchedConditions >= 3;
}
```

output:

```
true
true
false
false
false
```

Comment: Thanks, but your solution will return true for this password `Ab$12   34`, and spaces are not allowed, isn't it?

Comment: @DavidIsla check my edit, it´s still a lot better to read if you include a list for invalid character, where you could include everything that you don´t identiy as valid.

Comment: Sure, your solution is valid, that's right, but I want to know if there is a way to merge both. Thanks a lot!