# Password validation - lowercase, uppercase, numbers and special characters

Tags: javascript, c#, regex

How do I validate a password which has to meet the following conditions:

- minimum 8 characters
- 3 of the following 4 criteria met:

  1. lower case letters
  2. upper case letters
  3. numbers
  4. special symbols

Example:

```
rOckeFe11er - Valid (lowercase,uppercase,number)
jona$tHAn - Valid (lowercase, uppercase, special character)
jon134343 - invalid (lowercase,number) - should match at least 3 criteria
```

I tried using regular expression but finding it difficult with the 3 out of 4 criteria.

Comment: Can you post what you have tried with the regular expressions?

Comment: And this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22204836/regex-to-find-3-out-of-4-conditions

Comment: It would probably be easier to use 4 distinct regular expressions and return success when at least 3 of them are matching.