# Trouble implementing regular expression for password validation

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to use Javascript to validate a password given the following criteria:

- At least 9 characters long
- Uses at least 3/4 of these character types:

  - 2+ uppercase letters
  - 2+ lowercase letters
  - 2+ numbers
  - 2+ special characters

I'm trying to implement the latter criteria (2+ uppercase, 2+ lowercase, etc.) using the below pattern:

```
var pattern2=/^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[#?!@$%^&*-])(?=.*?[#?!@$%^&*-]).{9,}$/gi
```

However, it's not working. How would I fix this?

Comment: post your attempts..

Comment: Did you even try searching for answers first? This is common thing to do in JavaScript

Comment: lol i tired in at least two but cant ..i can make at least 1

Comment: @SallyAbdo have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5950756/regex-for-checking-that-at-least-3-of-4-different-character-groups-exist

Comment: Hope it helps ......:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
(?=(.*\d){2})(?=(.*[a-z]){2})(?=(.*[A-Z]){2})(?=.*[#?!@$%^&-]).{9,}
```

Tested [here](https://regex101.com/r/sE7dK6/2).

The regex above matches only if all the 4 requeriments are respected. If you want at least 3, then there's the monster:

```
((?=(.*\d){2})(?=(.*[a-z]){2})(?=(.*[A-Z]){2})|(?=(.*\d){2})(?=(.*[a-z]){2})(?=.*[#?!@$%^&-])|(?=(.*\d){2})(?=(.*[A-Z]){2})(?=.*[#?!@$%^&-])|(?=(.*[a-z]){2})(?=(.*[A-Z]){2})(?=.*[#?!@$%^&-])).{9,}
```

Also tested [here](https://regex101.com/r/fW8fG0/2)

Answer (score 0):

```
try this
if(userpassword.match(/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[!@#$%&\/=?_.,:;\\-])|(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#$%&\/=?_.,:;\\-]).{9,}$/)) {
    alert("right");
} else {
    alert("false");
}
```

Comment: You need one more set of parentheses to get the `^` and `$` to work correctly. (As written there are two gloabl alternatives - one beginning with the `^` and the other ending with the `$` - both anchors need to apply to both alternatives.)