# Regex to accept any 3 kinds of character but no space

Tags: regex

I wanted to allow regex to accept minimum of 8 characters and any 3 combinations out of following 4 categories.

1. One uppercase alpha character
2. One lowercase alpha character
3. One numeric character
4. One special character

The good thing is, there are many regex available for my requirement but most of them allows **space**.

The below regex meets my requirement but it allows space as well.

```
^.*(?=.{8,})(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[\d\W])(?=.*[!@#\$%&/=?_\.,:;-\\]).*$
```

and this one also allows space

```
^.*(?=.{8,})(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[\d\W])(?=.*[\S])
```

String should match:

1. `Testing123$`
2. `Testing123`
3. `Testing$`

String should NOT match:

1. `Test ing123`
2. `TESTING`
3. `Testing`
4. `TESTING1`
5. `testing1`
6. `testing$`

I tried to modify this in several ways but I couldn't succeed in writing a proper regex to validate a space along with 3 combinations as i mentioned above.

Regex source: [Regex for checking that at least 3 of 4 different character groups exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5950756/regex-for-checking-that-at-least-3-of-4-different-character-groups-exist)

> UPDATED with Answer:

This one accepts any 3 or 4 conditions but no space.

`^((?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])|(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[!@\#$%&/=?_.,:;\\-])|(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@\#$%&/=?_.,:;\\-])|(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@\#$%&/=?_.,:;\\-]))\S{8,}$`

Comment: This is not a regex writing service, and we're not going to leave this site to go elsewhere to figure out what you've tried. All relevant content (including sample text that should (and should *not*) match and your efforts to figure it out yourself) needs to be in your post *here*, not elsewhere. Please [edit] to make that happen. Thanks.

Comment: @KenWhite: I got it and it makes sense. I updated the regex along with my question.

Comment: Well, that's a third of what I asked for - it's a start. :-) Now where are the sample strings that *should* and *should not* match?

Comment: This problem is poorly suited for regular expressions.

Comment: just curious, are you trying to recreate a password field validator ?

Comment: @vasif: Kinda. I am trying this regex to add as an attribute in .net MVC model. I don't think there is an attribute option to validate any 3 combinations out of 4.

Comment: @DietrichEpp: I don't deny that at all. Escpecially, after a huge amount of research. For all my validations I am using regex, I don't feel like moving away for this requirement alon. Who knows? after an hour, i might give up :-)

Comment: Just change the last dot to `\S` (i.e., `\S*$`).  And **get rid of** the `.*` at the beginning; that never belonged there.

Comment: @Uba It looks like you've discovered a good explanation for why it's such a bad idea to use regular expressions for all of your validation.  Let me put it this way: there's nothing good about hammering screws into the wall.

Comment: Thanks @AlanMoore. I added \S at the end and it works perfectly fine. I did not remove .* at the begging as it throws syntax error. Thank you again!

Comment: That's still not right.  Have a look at my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex in your question in incorrect in several ways.  The first is that it requires all four kinds of character, not three out of four.  But I'll work with that to illustrate the other errors:

1. `\W` matches any non-word character, including spaces (which you don't want) and punctuation characters (including those listed in your fourth lookahead).  `(?=.*[\d\W])` should be just `(?=.*\d)`.
2. `[;-\\]` describes a range that includes all the uppercase letters plus several punctuation characters that you apparently didn't mean to allow.  You need to escape the hyphen, preferably by moving it to the end.
3. The `.*` at the beginning does nothing but make the regex less efficient, and one at the end should be `\S*`, to exclude whitespace.  But you might as well combine it with the length check: `\S{8,}$`.  (There used to be a good reason for putting the length check first, but I doubt anyone's using Internet Explorer 8 these days.)

Result:

```
^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[!@#$%&/=?_.,:;\\-])\S{8,}$
```

But, as I said, that requires all four conditions to be met.  The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5951177/20938) you copied the regex from missed the point of the question.  If you really need to enforce *three or four* of the conditions, use the regex from [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5951154/20938) and change the final `.` to `\S`.

Comment: Crystal clear explanation! Thanks, Alan. My expectation is to match 3 or 4 conditions but no space.I replaced period(.) in accepted answer regex with \S at the end. It works like a charm. I will update my question with correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
[! @#\$%&/=?_\.,:;-\\]
```

(added a space to your NOTs)

Comment: The idea is to *exclude* spaces, not to allow them.

Comment: Sorry, for some reason I was thinking you wanted to allow one space but only one space.  What I get for looking at questions at the end of the day!